# Change doctype in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt-mvp

I have a GWT MVP application and I use FormFactor to determine which version of the app to serve for Mobile, Tablet or Desktop.

My issue comes since Mobile version for IE needs a different doctype to work properly.
How can I change the doctype before I serve the app?

Answer (score 0):

This might change,using the script.

Detect user agent and then apply below codes...
var newDoctype = document.implementation.createDocumentType('html','-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN','http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtdd');

document.doctype.parentNode.replaceChild(newDoctype,document.doctype);